# Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am facing the following issue in entity framework core.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_MasterCountries_MasterLanguages_LanguageId' on table 'MasterCountries' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I have the following three entities:

**1. MasterCountry**

```
public class MasterCountry
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public MasterCurrency MasterCurrency { get; set; }
    public MasterLanguage MasterLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

**2. MasterCurrency**

```
public class MasterCurrency
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // Navigation Property
    public MasterCountry MasterCountry { get; set; }
}
```

**3. MasterLanguage**

```
public class MasterLanguage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // Navigation Property
    public ICollection<MasterCountry> MasterCountries { get; set; }
}
```

The **DbContext class** looks like the following:

```
public partial class NewProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MasterLanguage> MasterLanguages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MasterCurrency> MasterCurrencies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MasterCountry> MasterCountries { get; set; }

    public YouTemaDbContext(DbContextOptions<YouTemaDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .ApplyConfiguration(new MasterCurrencyConfiguration());

        builder
            .ApplyConfiguration(new MasterLanguageConfiguration());

        builder
            .ApplyConfiguration(new MasterCountryConfiguration());
    }
}
```

The configuration classes look like the following:

**1. MasterCountryConfiguration**

```
public class MasterCountryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MasterCountry>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MasterCountry> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        builder.Property(m => m.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250).IsUnicode();

        builder.Property(m => m.IsActive).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0);

        builder.Property(m => m.LanguageId).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(m => m.CurrencyId).IsRequired();

        builder
            .HasOne(m => m.MasterLanguage)
            .WithMany(a => a.MasterCountries)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.LanguageId);

        builder
            .HasOne(m => m.MasterCurrency)
            .WithOne(a => a.MasterCountry)
            .HasForeignKey<MasterCountry>(m => m.CurrencyId);

        builder.ToTable("MasterCountries");
    }
}
```

**2. MasterCurrencyConfiguration**

```
public class MasterCurrencyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MasterCurrency>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MasterCurrency> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        builder.Property(m => m.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250).IsUnicode();

        builder.Property(m => m.IsActive).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0);

        builder.ToTable("MasterCurrencies");
    }
}
```

**3. MasterLanguageConfiguration**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MasterLanguage> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        builder.Property(m => m.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250).IsUnicode();

        builder.Property(m => m.IsActive).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0);

        builder.ToTable("MasterLanguages");
    }
}
```

But while running the migration file, I get the following issue for MasterCurrency and MasterLanguage entities.

> CONSTRAINT [FK_MasterCountries_MasterCurrencies_CurrencyId] FOREIGN KEY ([CurrencyId]) REFERENCES [MasterCurrencies] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
>
> CONSTRAINT [FK_MasterCountries_MasterLanguages_LanguageId] FOREIGN KEY ([LanguageId]) REFERENCES [MasterLanguages] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE

I know that I have to set **Cascade** delete to **No Action** but since I am new to entity framework core so I am not sure where I have to do this.

Your help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please help me?